# Complex GIT cleanup

Tags: git, github

I was working on a big task on a `my-branch` branch which was create out of `develop`.
In the meantime, I was taking pulls from `develop`, thinking it was a good one.

After some time the `develop` branch was renamed to `test`.
Other developers were informed to make tests on the `test` branch.

I was informed that the `develop` branch was renamed to `test`, but I was not informed that I should start taking pulls (to merge) from `master`.

Then I started taking pulls from `master`.

Now `my-branch` has a lot of my work (good one), and a lot of tests - bad ones that should not be merged to master.

I need to:

- Remove from `my-branch` all the commits that: are not mine && are not in `master`

In other words, I need to remove all the commits other did, and those commits were not merged with `master`. This means those commits were tests/trash.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will work (assuming that your local `master`/`test` branches are already up-to-date with the remote ones):

```
git rebase --onto master test my-branch
```

This can be read like this: *git, **please**, rebase all revisions that are on `my-branch` on top of `master` but make sure to discard all revisions that make up the history of `test` branch..... thanks!*

This should be rebasing only revisions of yours, unless you did something funky.

Alternatively, if you are able to come up with a list of commits from `git log` that matches your requirements (log allows you to provide matching authors and being able to tell commits that should be excluded (`^exclude-commits-from-this-branch-or-commit`) and included (the normal `git log whatever`) so you can get a fancy list of commits like `git log --author="somebody" --reverse --no-merges --pretty="%h" ^exclude-from-here ^also-from-here this-is-what-i-want-to-rebase > commits.txt`). Then, you can cherry-pick them with:

```
git checkout --detach master
while read commit; do
    git cherry-pick $commit
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo There was an error cherry-picking $commit
        break
    fi
done < commits.txt
```

Comment: on which branch should I be when running this?

Comment: what branch will be 'edited' after running this command? will `master` be safe?

Comment: On which branch? Does not matter. git will end up working on `my-branch` when you run the rebase. And the branch that will be edited will be `my-branch`. The other branches won't be touched. If you do not feel confident, create a temporary branch: `git branch temp my-branch; git rebase --onto master test temp`.

Comment: Hello, it looks like that there is another branch that needs to be removed from that PR. It's called `test2`. Should a similar command, but instead of `master` use `my-branch`? Ex: git rebase --onto my-branch test2 very-new-branch` ?

Comment: Every situation is different and assessing what has to be done not having the repo in front of me is difficult. If you are able to understand what the 3 parameters that you are using with `git rebase` do and having in mind what you had done before, you should be able to know what the best way would be to use a different (later) rebase for a different branch.

Comment: Also if I check the list of PRs in the compare mode between `my-branch` before rebase and `master` and if I compare `my-branch-rebased` and `master` after running the command you suggested,in GitHub I see that they both have the same list of commits.However the rebased one has a lot of new commits in the day the rebase was made (probably it was the conficts fix).
If in compare mode old commits made to the `test` branch are still visible, does it mean that for some reason the rebase didn't remove them, or maybe the code is `removed` not from the commit list,but from the commits done in rebase?

Comment: The rebase used like that (`git rebase --onto A B C`) will rebase all revisions that are in the history of `C` that are _not_ in `B` and will put them one after the other on top of `A`.

Comment: In your particular problem, you needed to get rid of everything that was in the history of `test` branch (because that included all the commits that made the branch ready for testing) that's why it is `git rebase --onto master test my-branch`

Comment: hmm so that command was not what I needed. Because `my-branch` (`C`) at some point was created from `test` (`C`).

Comment: (all revisions that are in the history of C that are not in B) - the problem is that in C there is everything that is in B. What I need is to remove from `C`all that is in `B` that at the same time the commit was not done by me && is not in `A`

Comment: Sounds like you are getting the hang of it. :-) `git rebase` is very flexible. If you can come up with a list of revisions (just their IDs) that matches your requirement for what should be written on top of master (say, something like `git log --author="somebody" ^not-in-here yes-in-here --pretty='pick %h'` (have fun playing from there), you can then run a `git rebase -i --onto master whatever whatever` so that you can replace the list of revisions (see why I wrote pick in the `log --pretty`?). That should apply all the revisions you need on top of master.

Comment: ... or, if you get such list, cherry-pick them one after the other: `git checkout --detach master; git log --reverse --no-merges --author="somebody" ^not-in-here yes-in-here --pretty='%h' | while read revision; do git cherry-pick %i; done`. Or something like that.